# Убрать блокировку скриншота в играх, когда работает чит

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

Может я как то не правильно выразился, ну вот я делаю античит, и хочу скринить игру, но когда скриню с читом, то в скрине меню чита не отображается. Как то это можно обойти, нужно ли перехватывать какие нибудь ф-ии, как правильно поступить?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: К сожалеию, у нас тут у всех libastral забагована - мы не знаем, какую игру вы скрините. Передавайте иным способом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если игра написана на "directX"(90% всех игр) и чит перехватывает метод "Present" и через него отображает элементы меню, а скорее всего это так и есть, то все скриншоты которые ты будешь делать, будут делаться между методами "BeginScene" и "EndScene", а затем будет вызываться метод который меняет буферы местами (он же "Present"), в нем то "читер" и рисует меню, получается что меню рисуется уже после отрисовки всех объектов игры и вызова твоих скриншотов))) и поэтому он не отображается на скриншотах у тебя, выход какой?

1. Проверка на подмену оригинальной функции Presenta или EndScene, если функция подменена то там будет стоять инструкция jump на место где будет отрисовка меню читера, далее будет идти вызов оригинальной функции, снять сигнатуру оригинальной функции не затруднит вообще никак тебя, это просто, другое дело если читодел прошаренный и перехватит поинтер который идет из игры на интерфейс directX, тут уже динамическая память и ее практически нереально спалить.
2. Игру в оконный режим и сделать скриншот рабочего стола, но это так чисто от безысходности если, ибо самые прошаренные читоделы делают так, загружают свой модуль в игру, создают дочернее окно, инициализируют отдельный интерфейс directX и там все рисуют.

В общем скриншотер не самый лучший вариант отследить читера, ловить нужно изменения в самом клиенте игры, но тут тоже бабка на двое сказала, если чит будет построен по образу и подобию движка твоей игры, то ты никак не отследишь изменения в игре и читер будет безнаказанно "читерить"))), ну можно максимум сравнивать эталонные(максимальные значение которые могут быть) значения жизней, брони, восстановления бега там и т.д. и т.п.

Я не предлагаю готовые античиты типа FF, EAC, PB - ибо они стоят очень дорого для обычного человека, но вот комплексно отнестись к проблеме читерства можно, например скриншотер + скан игрового клиента на изменение памяти + поставить антиотладчик + проверять клиент на наличие в нем лишних модулей(dll), проверять список процессов системы на загруженные приложения и их модули типа "ida", "olly" и др. В общем если сесть и подумать то можно много чего изобрести))

**UPD:**

С видео та же беда что и со скринами, чтобы снять видео фрапс, ну или другая программа для записи видео, хукает, да хукает!!!, точно так же как и читер рисует свое меню))), ну не совсем также, более сложно и профессионально( при желании исходники можно найти на гитхабе), так вот как работает прога для записи видео - она делает "скриншот" кадра игры, если это можно так назвать и затем кодирует в видео, меню читера рисуется после этого "скриншота", вот его и не видно, тут есть два нюанса, которые тебе на руку - 1. Если игру "записывать в оконном режиме"(записывать придется рабочий стол!!! чтобы все было видно), то меню чита будет видно. 2.Хук фрапса, ну или другого приложения для записи видео с игры сильно конфликтует с "хуком читера" и может происходить краш игры.

**UPD2:**

Что делать в данном случае? я вот точно не знаю, есть хороший античит "EAC" платный или бесплатный? скорее всего платный, лучше уточнить на офсайте, вот он отлично защищает от внедрения внешних модулей в приложение, в твоем случае это КСГО, попробуй его, глянь на ютубе настройку этого античита, в итоге читеры не смогут напрямую изменять память игры, а так же внедрять в клиент модули), что даст отличную защиту.

Comment: Так как анти чит делаю для одного турнира, то можно всех попросить сделать, оконный режим, т.к. по сути простой вариант.  Анти чит делаю для игры  CS:GO, т.к. там очень сильно любят читерить. А вот интересно, в основном там читы на WH, и как мне узнать изменения внутриигрового процесса, так как мало с этим дружу, но очень хочу научится как то правильно этим всем пользоваться. По сути мне нужно сделать, какой то универсальный способ.  И кстати, очень стало интересно,  когда снимал видео, то тоже не видно ни WH и т.д. Это как? Они тоже подменяют эти же самые ф-ии? Спасибо за развернутый ответ))

Comment: @HackMemory, в связи с твоим вопросом обновил свой ответ, ибо он не поместился в коммент

Comment: Таки да,  давайте уточню. Так скажем мой античит, это как бы дополнение к EAC, и его все ровно обходят "читерята", я кое что сделал, я беру снимаю видео с экрана, отправляю на свой сервер. Там просматриваю, но я обойти все тоже можно, я хочу найти все обходы которые есть. Попала идея просто скриншотить игру, но и тут они выигрывают. Что тогда мне делать. Мне нужно как то раньше чита заинжектиться и проверять на подмену, так ли?

Comment: @HackMemory, блин интересно как они его обходят...На счет того что делать - скриншоть игру, проверяй место которое хукают читерята, чтобы понять что это за место посмотри урок по созданию директикс хука https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muyeG_S3xYc&list=PLc_QQC_Xnp8texIbnFYEIipDGApNRa9ke&index=5 и сразу все поймешь, именно какое место проверять в модуле "d3d9.dl" и тогда обычным фаинд паттерном сканируй память клиента? но блин если есть еас то нужно сделать так чтобы он запускал клиент игры и тогда никто не сможет нечего загрузить в клиент и это будет лучшая защита